# How to capture snap of window including title bar

Tags: c#, screenshot

below is my routine which works fine but the routine is not generating the image of window including title bar. so guide me what i need to change in code.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{

            if (m.Msg == WM_COMMAND && m.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_MINIMIZE)
            {
                OnMinimize(EventArgs.Empty);
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
}

protected virtual void OnMinimize(EventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle r = this.RectangleToScreen(ClientRectangle);

    if (_lastSnapshot == null)
    {
        _lastSnapshot = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
    }

    using (Image windowImage = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height))
    using (Graphics windowGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(windowImage))
    using (Graphics tipGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(_lastSnapshot))
    {
        windowGraphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(r.Left, r.Top), new Point(0, 0), new Size(r.Width, r.Height));
        windowGraphics.Flush();

        tipGraphics.DrawImage(windowImage, 0, 0, r.Width, r.Height);
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

ur code works but some top left portion is not ok. so here i am uploading the image which i have generated using ur code. please have a look and tell me what i need to fix in the code. form width is not coming properly. thanks
[image]

### UPDATE

```
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
    this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
    bmp.Save(@"d:\Zapps.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply get the height of the title bar and add it to the height of the area to be captured (and subtract it from the current top of the image - check the source below for the changes):

```
protected virtual void OnMinimize(EventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle r = this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);
    int titleHeight = r.Top - this.Top;

    _lastSnapshot = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);

    using (Image windowImage = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height + titleHeight))
    using (Graphics windowGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(windowImage))
    using (Graphics tipGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(_lastSnapshot))
    {
        windowGraphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(r.Left, r.Top - titleHeight),
                 new Point(0, 0), new Size(r.Width, r.Height + titleHeight));
        windowGraphics.Flush();

        tipGraphics.DrawImage(windowImage, 0, 0, r.Width, r.Height + titleHeight);
        _lastSnapshot.Save(@".\tmp.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: ur code works but some top left portion is not ok. so here i am uploading the image which i have generated using ur code. please have a look and tell me what i need to fix in the code. form width is not coming properly. thanks

Comment: It looks like you still set your `_lastSnapshot = new Bitmap(100, 100);`? Or the width of the Graphics object you are saving, which would be `_lastSnapshot`. Verify whether you set its width the same way I do at all locations. Was the width displayed correctly before you applied the changes for showing the title bar? I did actually try the code above this time and it does work fine for me. It captures the whole form here ^^ In fact, I just copied and pasted the code above back into my application and got a properly formatted image.

Comment: i just copy and paste ur code...nothing change but picture which was generated from ur code does not look ok.

Comment: You are initializing `_lastSnapshot` outside of the method. Ergo it is not null when it enters the method and its width never gets set properly. Remove the check for `_lastSnapshot == null`. Else the application will never reset the size of the new bitmap. See my edit.

Comment: still the problem is there and i could understand why full width is not coming.on the left & right side there is non-client area which is not being visible and that is why right picture looks odd.do u know how calculate width with the width of non-client area of form?

Comment: i am taking the snap of form1 from form1 load method and form1 is sdi form under a mdi apps.

Comment: Then it wont work. If the UI does not paint the control you wont be able to copy it. One would think that the window/control-content is *there*, as in real life, if it was a picture or the like it would be there (some philosophs wouldnt even agree to that, but thats another matter). In this case - controls that are not visible are not drawn and therefore you cannot copy them into a bitmap - at least not this very simple way and whatever way would be possible extends my current knowledge and also this comment section here. It does work in WPF but most of it is done behind the scenes (not a pun)

Comment: i like to request u that star a c# project and add two forms there.create one of the form mdi container and from the mid form open another sdi form.put a button on the sdi form and call ur code from button on click event and then u can see what kind of image u r getting. i think some modification would be require in the code to work it perfectly.

Comment: i got the right code.the right code is updated in my question. thanks