# CopyFromScreen coordinates off

Tags: c#, winforms, screenshot

This is a followup to a previous question- sorry if followups are against the rules! I wasn't sure and wanted to be able to give full answer credit to whoever answered this question as well.

I am trying to get a screenshot of a particular section of my form, and am using CopyFromScreen to do it. I needed a screenshot of a panel, and then items that reside over the panel (there are buttons floating over it).

Anyhow, when I tried implementing it, the screenshot came out as being super far to the top left of the panel. Rather than the screenshot being of the panel itself, only a small portion of the panel is visible on the bottom right of the picture and the area above and to the left of the panel is what is actually pictured.

My implementation is off somewhere and I'm not entirely sure where. Can you guys see what I did wrong? (again- the screenshot should just be a picture of the panel area. Nothing else).

```
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.CopyFromScreen(panel1.Left, panel1.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        bmp.Save("Test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use CopyFromScreen you have to give screen coordinates, here you give coordinates relative to your form.

what you should do is: (if your code is in the form containing the panel)

```
int borderWidth = (this.Width – this.ClientSize.Width) /2;
int titleBarHeight = this.Height – this.ClientSize.Height – 2 * BorderWidth;
g.CopyFromScreen(this.Left + panel1.Left + titleBarHeight, this.Top + panel1.Top + borderWidth, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

Comment: That's very close! However, it is still a little off to the left and a bit more on the top. Can you think of any reason why that deviation would exist? 

This is what it should look like (just captured using keyboard + paint, not programmatically): http://i.imgur.com/aJpSXy7.jpg
This is what it came out as: http://i.imgur.com/pgi6NRq.jpg

Comment: yes, it comes from the fact that borders aren't included in the client area, so you need to add the size of the borders to the rest (don't remember how you get that)

Comment: Perfect! Now that I have an idea of what is causing the issue, I can figure the rest out. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: here: http://ivision.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/title-bar-height-and-form-border-width-of-net-form/

Answer (score 2):

Better answer could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15334320/3090544). 
In the link there is the correct calculation to get the upper left corner of the form independent of the FormBorderStyle.

```
Rectangle r = this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);
int titleHeight = r.Top - this.Top;
int borderWidth = r.Left - this.Left; 

g.CopyFromScreen(this.Left + borderWidth + panel1.Left, this.Top + titleHeight + panel1.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```